# In Java , Exclude a string while encode using base64

Tags: java, base64, decode, encode, tiff

Is there a way that I can exclude particular string `(II*)` while encode a `tiff` file and keep that `String` as it is and also during the **decode** ?

Or

How can I specify the encoding to always **encode** `(II*)` as three characters and not to combine with any other characters ?

Below code to replace the string II* with (  II*  ), however tiff got corrupted after that.

```
           Path path = Paths.get("D:\\Users\\Vinoth\\workspace\\Testing\\Testing.tiff");
            Charset charset = StandardCharsets.UTF_8;

            String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(path), charset);
            content = content.replace("II*", "  II  ");
            content = content.replace("  II  ","  II*  ");
            Files.write(path, content.getBytes(charset));
```

Comment: please add some code snippet to identify the problem in your code .. Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately that cannot be done. Bytes to string and inverse use a charset conversion, which is expensive (slow and twice/thrice the memory), causes data corruption (i.e. with UTF-8) and TIFF is a binary format one cannot stretch.

Comment: Is there a way that I can separate the tiff ? Inside my tiff file the images are separated by II* , So I need to loop through the tiff file and separate the images individually to a tiff files. for example. Start the substring from II* to the begining of another II* and goes on until find the end .